# Proving Independence using joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A certain compound that is used in forming a composite structural materiel depends on the interaction of two materials X & Y the percentage of having material X and Y within the composite varies from 15% to 35% and 20% to 35%, respectively however a sample is considered to be failed if the existence of each X and Y exceeds 30% of the overall composed suppose that the joint density function of these random variables is

$f(x,y)$ =
\begin{cases} 
      c(x+2y) & 0.15<x< 0.35, 0.2<y<0.35 \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}

Determine:

1. The constant c
2. The marginal pdf of X and Y
3. Are the two random variables independent? why?
4. The probability of having a failed sample.

My questions are about question 3 and 4

For question 3 if the combination of $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ we got from question 2 not equal to the $f(x,y)$ then random variables are dependent, is that right?

and for number 4 we do integration twice of $f(x,y)$ in regards to $dx,dy$ and the limits of integration will be from 0.3 to 0.35 for both integration? is that correct and are the integration limits correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems right to me. Welcome to stack exchange. :)

Comment: @Delsilon thank you very much